# SlimDX Direct3D 11 Indexing Problems

Tags: c#, graphics, indexing, direct3d, slimdx

I'm trying to draw an indexed square using SlimDX and Direct3D11. I've managed to draw a square without indices, but when I swap to my indexed version I just get a blank screen.

My input layout is set to only take position data (I'm essentially extending from the third tutorial on the SlimDX website) and to draw Triangle Lists.

My render loop code is as follows (I am using the triangle.fx pixel and vertex shader files from the tutorial, they take vertex positions (in screen coordinates) and paint them yellow, D3D is shorthand for SlimDX.Direct3D11)

```
//clear the render target
context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderTarget, new Color4(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f));
context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(mesh.VertexBuffer,12, 0));
context.InputAssembler.SetIndexBuffer(mesh.IndexBuffer, Format.R16_UNorm, 0);
context.DrawIndexed(mesh.indices, 0, 0);
swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
```

"mesh" is a struct that holds a Vertex buffer, Index buffer and vertex count. The data is filled here:

```
Vertex[] vertexes = new Vertex[4];
vertexes[0].Position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0.5f);
vertexes[1].Position = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
vertexes[2].Position = new Vector3(0.5f, 0, 0.5f);
vertexes[3].Position = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

UInt16[] indexes = { 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 };
DataStream vertices = new DataStream(12 * 4, true, true);
foreach (Vertex vertex in vertexes)
{
    vertices.Write(vertex.Position);
}
vertices.Position = 0;
DataStream indices = new DataStream(sizeof(int) * 6, true, true);
foreach (UInt16 index in indexes)
{
    indices.Write(index);
}
indices.Position = 0;
mesh = new Mesh();
D3D.Buffer vertexBuffer = new D3D.Buffer(device, vertices, 12 * 4, ResourceUsage.Default, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.None, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);
mesh.VertexBuffer = vertexBuffer;
mesh.IndexBuffer = new D3D.Buffer(device, indices, 2 * 6, ResourceUsage.Default, BindFlags.IndexBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.None, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);
mesh.vertices = vertexes.GetLength(0);
mesh.indices = indexes.Length;
```

All of this is nearly identical to my unindexed square method (with the addition of index buffers and indices, and the removal of two duplicate vertices that aren't needed with indexing), but while the unindexed method draws a square, the indexed method doesn't.

My current theory is that there is either something wrong with this line:

```
mesh.IndexBuffer = new D3D.Buffer(device, indices, 2 * 6, ResourceUsage.Default, BindFlags.IndexBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.None, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);
```

Or these lines:

```
context.InputAssembler.SetIndexBuffer(mesh.IndexBuffer, Format.R16_UNorm, 0);
context.DrawIndexed(mesh.indices, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use a vertex and indexbuffer for this simple example?

Like this way (Directx9):

```
VertexBuffer vb;
IndexBuffer ib;

vertices = new PositionColored[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
//vertex creation
vb = new VertexBuffer(device, HEIGHT * WIDTH * PositionColored.SizeInBytes, Usage.WriteOnly, PositionColored.Format, Pool.Default);
DataStream stream = vb.Lock(0, 0, LockFlags.None);
stream.WriteRange(vertices);
vb.Unlock();

indices = new short[(WIDTH - 1) * (HEIGHT - 1) * 6];
//indicies creation
ib = new IndexBuffer(device, sizeof(int) * (WIDTH - 1) * (HEIGHT - 1) * 6, Usage.WriteOnly, Pool.Default, false);
DataStream stream = ib.Lock(0, 0, LockFlags.None);
stream.WriteRange(indices);
ib.Unlock();

//Drawing
device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target | ClearFlags.ZBuffer, Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1.0f, 0);
device.BeginScene();
device.VertexFormat = PositionColored.Format;
device.SetStreamSource(0, vb, 0, PositionColored.SizeInBytes);
device.Indices = ib;
device.SetTransform(TransformState.World, Matrix.Translation(-HEIGHT / 2, -WIDTH / 2, 0) * Matrix.RotationZ(angle));
device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, WIDTH * HEIGHT, 0, indices.Length / 3);
device.EndScene();
device.Present();
```

I use the mesh in another way (directx9 code again):

```
        private void CreateMesh()
        {
            meshTerrain = new Mesh(device, (WIDTH - 1) * (HEIGHT - 1) * 2, WIDTH * HEIGHT, MeshFlags.Managed, PositionColored.Format);
            DataStream stream = meshTerrain.VertexBuffer.Lock(0, 0, LockFlags.None);
            stream.WriteRange(vertices);
            meshTerrain.VertexBuffer.Unlock();
            stream.Close();
            stream = meshTerrain.IndexBuffer.Lock(0, 0, LockFlags.None);
            stream.WriteRange(indices);
            meshTerrain.IndexBuffer.Unlock();
            stream.Close();

            meshTerrain.GenerateAdjacency(0.5f);
            meshTerrain.OptimizeInPlace(MeshOptimizeFlags.VertexCache);

            meshTerrain = meshTerrain.Clone(device, MeshFlags.Dynamic, PositionNormalColored.Format);
            meshTerrain.ComputeNormals();
        }


        //Drawing
        device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target | ClearFlags.ZBuffer, Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1.0f, 0);    
        device.BeginScene();
        device.VertexFormat = PositionColored.Format;
        device.SetTransform(TransformState.World, Matrix.Translation(-HEIGHT / 2, -WIDTH / 2, 0) * Matrix.RotationZ(angle));

        int numSubSets = meshTerrain.GetAttributeTable().Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < numSubSets; i++)
        {
            meshTerrain.DrawSubset(i);
        }
        device.EndScene();
        device.Present();
```

Comment: The Mesh class isn't available in the Direct3D11 namespace which I'm using (sorry, should have said!), Mesh in my code is a struct I created. I'm not sure how well the Direct3D9 code (I'm actually eventually planning on converting an old MDX project to run in SlimDX Direct3D11) translates to DX11, but I'll give it a go

Comment: Try the code listed here: http://www.rkoenig.eu/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=21:chapter-3-das-erste-echte-3d-objekt&catid=6:directx10-basics&Itemid=3